# Unexpected token '-UFormat' in expression or statement

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to fetch the list of

- full path name of files/folders
- last write time of files/folders
- size of files/folders

based on which of the 3 pieces of information the end user wants.
I'm looking to expanding this function of mine to accommodate more properties based on inputs provided. Given below is a snippet of my code and the failure following it.

- `$Path` is a path, it's an input
- `$CustomMetaList` is an array of properties, it's an input.

```bsh
    $BaseCmd = "Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse"
    $Hidden = ""
    $FullName = ""
    $LastWriteTime = ""
    $Size = ""
    $PropList = ""
    $CustomMetaList = $CustomMetaList.split(",")
    foreach ($Meta in $CustomMetaList) {
        if ($Meta -eq "'Hidden'") {
            $Hidden = "-Force"
        }
        if ($Meta -eq "'FullName'") {
            $PropList = [String]::Join(",","@{e={`$_.FullName};width=250}")
        }
        if ($Meta -eq "'LastWriteTimeUtc'") {
            $PropList = [String]::Join(",",$PropList,"@{e={`$_.LastWriteTimeUtc -UFormat %s}}")
        }
        if ($Meta -eq "'Size'") {
            $PropList = [String]::Join(",",$PropList,"@{e={`$_.Length}}")
        }
    }
    Invoke-Expression "$BaseCmd $Hidden | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -Property $PropList -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 5000"
}
```

I receive the following error when I try to run my script, 
Do ou have any idea on what's wrong ?

```
Invoke-Expression :
At line:1 char:210
+ ... stWriteTimeUtc -UFormat %s}},@{e={$_.Length}} -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 5000
+                    ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-UFormat' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:219
+ ... meUtc -UFormat %s}},@{e={$_.Length}} -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 5000
+                    ~~
Unexpected token '%s' in expression or statement.
At E:\299955427760_GetData.ps1:114 char:5
+           Invoke-Expression "$BaseCmd $Hidden | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -Proper ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Comment: [Invoke-Expression is considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). Do not use it.

Comment: instead of building a command to run, why not just run the base command,  send that thru `Select-Object` to build an object that contains only the wanted properties, and finally send that to `Format-Object`? ///// i can't see ANY reason to do things as ... backwards ... as what you have done there. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey it's a weird anti-pattern I've seen among ps newbies where they generate some string of commands and use `Invoke-Expression` to run it instead of just... running the string of commands.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - i suppose you are correct. [*grin*] hopefully the OP will describe the _why_ of it from his point of view.

Comment: Thanks @TheIncorrigible1, I'll keep this in mind going forward, the basic idea behind my approach was to build the command as a string based on what inputs (for the properties such as name, size, lwt) the user provides. A quick online search for what I wanted led me to Invoke-Expression. I didn't check to see if it was the best approach though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) soundly advises, [Invoke-Expression should be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/), because there are almost always better solutionsand it comes with security risks.

Generally, **for iteratively constructing commands with varying arguments, argument [*splatting*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) is the best solution**, though in your case that's not strictly necessary - see bottom section.

However, **your problem is unrelated to the use of `Invoke-Expression`**, because it is the following expression that causes your problem:

```
$_.LastWriteTimeUtc -UFormat %s  # !! Syntax error
```

You can only pass `-UFormat` to the `Get-Date` cmdlet, not to a variable or expression:

```
Get-Date -Date $_.LastWriteTimeUtc -UFormat %s  # OK
```

Additionally, due to a bug in Windows PowerShell v.5.1 (since corrected in PowerShell *Core*), `Get-Date -UFormat %s` outputs *fractional* seconds too, which is incorrect; you can fix this by simply casting to `[int]`:

```
[int] (Get-Date -Date $_.LastWriteTimeUtc -UFormat %s)
```

(Even without the bug present you may want to do this in order to receive a *numeric* result, given that `Get-Date -UFormat` always outputs *strings*).

As an aside: Another bug causes the result to be based on *local* times by default, whereas Unix time stamps are required to be *UTC*-based; since you're using property `.LastWriteTimeUtc`, your code is not affected.

---

**Here's a solution that avoids `Invoke-Expression` and is much shorter too:**

```
# Sample input values.
$Path = $env:TEMP
$CustomMetaList = 'FullName,Size,LastWriteTimeUtc'

# Construct the array of property definitions to pass to Select-Object
# based on the custom list, and record in $force whether hidden items 
# should be included.
$props = switch ($CustomMetaList -split ',') {
    'Hidden' { $force = $True; continue } # save in Boolean var.
    'FullName' { $_; continue }           # same name as property
    'Size' { 'Length'; continue }         # map 'Size' to 'Length'
    'LastWriteTimeUtc' {                  # calculated property
      @{ n=$_; e = { [int] (Get-Date -Date $_.LastWriteTimeUtc -UFormat %s) } }
    }
}


Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Force:$force | 
  Format-Table -Property $props -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize |
    Out-String -Width 5000
```

Note how `switch` is used to implicitly iterate over the elements of the array that `$CustomMetaList -split ','` returns.
The branch handlers of a `switch` statement are *all* tested for by default, so `continue` is used to short-circuit that, once a match has been found. Caveat: Do *not* use `break`, as it stops iterating over further array elements.

The output from the iterations of the `switch` statement is implicitly collected in an *array* stored in `$props`, which is later passed to `Format-Table`.

`-Force:$force` is a way to mimic the effects of passing / not passing switch parameter `-Force`: if `$force` is `$true`, it is the same as if just `-Force` had been passed; otherwise, it is treated as if `-Force` had not been passed.

This will yield something like:

```
FullName                              Length LastWriteTimeUtc
--------                              ------ ----------------
C:\path\to\sample.txt                 51     1543853694
# ...
```